# Search after occurring a special word

Tags: c#, regex, search

How can I search after occurring a word for example imagine the following string :

```
   The Fisrt Colors 
       red green yellow
       blue white violet
       red green orange
   The Second Colors
       red black white 
       green cyan magenta
       red magenta blue
```

I need to search the lines that contains `red` and they are after `The Second Colors` in the above example the expecting result is :

```
red black white 
red magenta blue
```

I do the simple search with :

```
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(MyString, @"[\n\r].*red\s*([^\n\r]*)"))
        {

        }
```

but the above code doesn't work in this scenario cuz it returns

```
    red green yellow
    red green orange
    red black white 
    red magenta blue
```

**Edit 1 :**
As @Jonesopolis comments , What if `The Second Colors` were moved above `The First Colors` . I mean how to limit the results between these two title (For example the `The Second Colors` and `The Third Colors` ?

Comment: Is "The Second Colors" a constant keyword for you? If it is, you can substring your string at first, and then find the matches by RegEx

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan no ! It is not a constant keyword

Comment: @ᔕIᑎᗩKᗩᖇᐯᗩᑎᗪI: What *is* constant here? You want to match something between boundaries. Please define these boundaries. Otherwise, it is impossible to provide a valid answer.

Comment: @stribizhev actually the constant is <h1>The Header</h1> and in above example its : <h1>The Second Colors</h1> so I thing the constant is <h1>  but cuz I don't wanna change the question form , it is better to give The Second Colors as a constant word .

Comment: @ᔕIᑎᗩKᗩᖇᐯᗩᑎᗪI: It is now clear as rain that you are parsing HTML with regex. And it would be easier to do it right: 1) use HTML parser to get the right H1, 2) get the necessary lines. Now, *The Second Colors* is the starting boundary. What is the trailing one?

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you but after this question I solved my question in another way by using HtmlAgilityPack and you can download it from https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ this library is flexible and efficient way.

Comment: I know HTMLAgilityPack, I have used it often. If you had posted the whole HTML at the beginning, you most probably would have been heavily downvoted, but you would have got a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex are a powerful tool when you have to match a pattern, however when you start adding logic to the pattern is easy to fall in an ugly scenario.

So, you could use two regex to ease your work. For instance, you can use a first regex to extract the content for `Second Colors` like this:

```
Second Colors([\s\S]*?)(?:The|$)
```

[First step demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW2gW5/1)

And then capture the pattern with red as you stated with this second approach:

```
(red.*)
```

[Second step demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW2gW5/2)

This approach is cleaner than having one monster regex to make the trick

**Update**: as **[stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev)** mentioned in his comment, you can actually replace the trick of `[\s\S]` by the wildcard `.` and leverage the single line flag. So you can have:

```
(?s)Second Colors(.*?)(?:The|$)
```

And you will have a regex with a better performance.

Comment: Why use `[\s\S]*?`? Lazy dot matching `(?s).*?` is not a good idea when you parse blocks of plain text. Imagine there is a thousand lines of varied width. What if `The` appears somewhere *inside* the `The SecondColors* block?

Comment: @stribizhev totally agreed, single line flag has a better performance over the `\s\S` trick. Wil update the answer with your comments

Comment: Well, the best performance depends on the expected length of the input. I'd rather consider an unroll-the-loop technique here.

Comment: @stribizhev done. Btw, I'd need to post a question so you can explain me that lol

Answer (score -1):

```
(?<=\bThe Second Colors\b[\s\S]*?)[\n\r].*red\s*([^\n\r]*)
```

Use variable `lookbehind`.[See demo.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5CbThe%20Second%20Colors%5Cb%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F)%5B%5Cn%5Cr%5D.*red%5Cs*(%5B%5E%5Cn%5Cr%5D*)&i=%20%20%20The%20Fisrt%20Colors%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20red%20green%20yellow%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20blue%20white%20violet%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20red%20green%20orange%0D%0A%20%20%20The%20Second%20Colors%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20red%20black%20white%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20green%20cyan%20magenta%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20red%20magenta%20blue)

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  If `The Second Colors` were moved above `The first Colors`, it matches too much.  [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cbThe+Second+Colors%5cb%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f)%5b%5cn%5cr%5d.*red%5cs*(%5b%5e%5cn%5cr%5d*)&i=+++The+Second+Colors%0d%0a+++++++red+black+white+%0d%0a+++++++green+cyan+magenta%0d%0a+++++++red+magenta+blue%0d%0a%0d%0a+++The+Fisrt+Colors+%0d%0a+++++++red+green+yellow%0d%0a+++++++blue+white+violet%0d%0a+++++++red+green+orange%0d%0a)